# Send Emails with html_message

Tags: python, django, email, django-email

I want to send HTML-email, using Django templates like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello <strong>{{ message }}</strong> - your account is activated.
</body>
</html>
```

Also I want to send data from the backend with the Email. In this example I want to send a message from the backend with the email template.

Here is my View:

```
def home(request):
    message_name = "NAME"
    message_email = "EMAIL"
    message = "USER"
    msg_html = render_to_string('email/email.html')

    send_mail(
        'message from ' + message_name,  # subject
        message,  # message
        message_email,  # from email
        ['myemail@outlook.de'],  # To Email
        html_message=msg_html,
    )
    context = {'message': message, 'message_name': message_name, 'message_email': message_email}
    return render(request, 'email/email.html', context)
```

When I receive the Email I only get the text and not the {{ message }} which would be **USER** in this example.

Comment: `send_mail('message from ' + message_name, message,...` -> `send_mail('message from ' + message_name, message=message,...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in the context into your `render_to_string` call. `render_to_string` takes the template and returns HTML with the passed context. That you can then pass to `send_mail`. So change the code to:

```
[...]
message_name = 'NAME'
message_email = 'EMAIL'
message = 'USER'
context = {'message': message, 'message_name': message_name, 'message_email': message_email}
msg_html = render_to_string('email/email.html', context=context)
[...]
```